# python dictionary - how to search and display answers

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to use a database implemented as a dictionary to search for a user entered value and if that value is found, it is displayed or else an error message is displayed. 
'uuc' or 'uum' etc refers to abbreviations for a university campus.

The user should be able to enter one of the above values and any matches should be displayed. However, this doesn't work in my code and I can't locate the problem.

```
def all_from(datab,university):
l = len(datab)
k = 1
i = 0
while k <= 1:
    s = datab[k]
    the_university = s[2]
    if university == the_university:
        i = i + 1
        print datab[k]
    k = k + 1
if i == 0:
    print 'Nobody goes to University there!'

datab = dict()
datab[1] = ['walker','matthew','uuc',1]
datab[2] = ['stewart','rory','uum',2]
datab[3] = ['toner','kevin','qub',4]
datab[4] = ['hughes','johnny','uuj',1]
datab[5] = ['douglas','kenny','uuc', 3]
datab[6] = ['hooks', 'peter','qub',1]
datab[7] = ['campbell','vicky','uuj',2]
datab[8] = ['crooks','laura','uum',4]
datab[9] = ['irwin','emma','uuc',3]
datab[10] = ['patterson','steve','uuc',1]

university = (raw_input('Enter the University here: '))
all_from(datab,university)
```

Comment: why don't you make a dictionary with the college as the key and the people list as the value? what does the number represent in the list?

Comment: Can you provide more contextual information of what data is stored in the dict and how the application may need to retrieve it?
What does the key, first column, second column, third column and forth column mean? Which of them need to be searchable?

Comment: @Adirio There are four field names for the data. From left to right; surname, forename, university campus and university year. So I need to search for all university campus' for a user inputted value - e.g. - 'uum'. So this should return people that have 'uum' as their university campus

Comment: The while loop is wrong. I think you meant to use "while k <= l:" instead of "while k <= 1:".

Comment: You aren't really using dictionaries correctly. It would be better to have a list of dictionary entries rather than a dictionary of list entries. For example `datab = [{'name':'bob','campus':'uum'}, {'name':'alan','campus':'uuc'}]`

Comment: @scotty3785 would this make it easier to search for values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My contribution. I feel that arranging the students as items in a list, with the different fields as dictionary keys is a better data structure.

```
def find_all(datab,uni):
    for student in datab:
        if student['uni'] == uni:
            print(student)

datab = []
datab.append( {'lastname':'walker', 'firstname':'matthew','uni':'uuc','year':1})
datab.append( {'lastname':'stewart','firstname':'rory','uni':'uum','year':2})
datab.append( {'lastname':'toner','firstname':'kevin','uni':'qub','year':4})
datab.append( {'lastname':'hughes','firstname':'johnny','uni':'uuj','year':1})

uni = input('Enter the uni here: ')
find_all(datab,uni)
```

If you want to search through all the keys then you could change the 
`if student['uni'] == uni` line to

```
for key, value in student.items():
    if value == uni:
```

**Another version:** this will allow you to enter a very simple query.

```
def find_all(datab,query):
    query = query.split('OR')
    for search_terms in query:
        for student in datab:
            for key, value in student.items():
                if value == search_terms.strip():
                    print(student)



datab = list()
datab.append( {'lastname':'walker', 'firstname':'matthew','uni':'uuc','year':'1'})
datab.append( {'lastname':'stewart','firstname':'rory','uni':'uum','year':'2'})
datab.append( {'lastname':'toner','firstname':'kevin','uni':'qub','year':'4'})
datab.append( {'lastname':'hughes','firstname':'johnny','uni':'uuj','year':'1'})

query = input('Enter your query here: ')
find_all(datab,query)
```

Here is my code running with two simple queries

```
Enter the uni here: uum OR uuc
{'firstname': 'rory', 'lastname': 'stewart', 'uni': 'uum', 'year': 2}
{'firstname': 'matthew', 'lastname': 'walker', 'uni': 'uuc', 'year': 1}

Enter your query here: 1 OR UUM
{'firstname': 'matthew', 'lastname': 'walker', 'uni': 'uuc', 'year': '1'}
{'firstname': 'johnny', 'lastname': 'hughes', 'uni': 'uuj', 'year': '1'}
```

You just add the word OR between the items and it will search for any item in the dictionary that contains any of the words. N.B. I had to change the uni year to be a string to get it working.

As I've stated. This would be much better with a proper database like SQLite.

Comment: That looks better laid out than other answers. How would I Alter it to search for people that attend 'qub' and 'uuj' for example? I want to be able to search for multiple rather than just one

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think I've correctly interpreted what you are looking for

Comment: However reading again I think you want to be able to do a search to get all the people who are at 'qub' OR 'uuj' (since one can't be at two uni's at once). In this case, we'd need to expand the code to accept a list of uni's rather than just a single entry. This is sounding more like a job for something like sqlite (which is a proper database)

Comment: I want to display everyone who is at 'qub' and 'uuj' into one list. Is this possible without being too complicated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128854/discussion-between-matthew-willis-and-scotty3785).

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your `all_from` function:

```
def all_from(datab,university):

    # Create flag to see if there are results
    result = False
    for k in datab.keys():
        # Knowing that university will always be in the same column
        if university == datab[k][2]:
            result = True
            print datab[k]
    if not result:
        print 'Nobody goes to University there!'


datab = dict()
datab[1] = ['walker','matthew','uuc',1]
datab[2] = ['stewart','rory','uum',2]
datab[3] = ['toner','kevin','qub',4]
datab[4] = ['hughes','johnny','uuj',1]
datab[5] = ['douglas','kenny','uuc', 3]
datab[6] = ['hooks', 'peter','qub',1]
datab[7] = ['campbell','vicky','uuj',2]
datab[8] = ['crooks','laura','uum',4]
datab[9] = ['irwin','emma','uuc',3]
datab[10] = ['patterson','steve','uuc',1]

university = (raw_input('Enter the University here: '))
all_from(datab,university)
```

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_wjXMwt73xI_2.py

Comment: Unless someone is named as a university campus. Let's hope there is no John uuc.

Comment: True, I should fix that.